# Altering table to add new column with nullable true

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I am writing a migration file in `typeorm` I wanted to add an extra column to my existing table.
I am writing the following query

`await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE "me" ADD COLUMN "id" VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL');`

with the above query, I gt the following error:
`RSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"me" ADD COLUMN "id" VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL' at line 1`,`

I just want that my column is `nullable`, also I want to set `Collation` to  `utf8mb4_bin`.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to double quote around table and column name.

```
ALTER TABLE me ADD COLUMN id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Furthermore, the `id` column usually is `auto increment int` and `primary key` field.So if you want to name a string field `id`, it maybe ambiguous.